# Vuetify theme not applied, when not using npm or webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I try to build a Vue and Vuetify solution (also using httpVueLoader) to get a solution with Vue but without using npm or anything alike (just old school inclusion of javascript files). I used the simple login form layout to test setting them colors, but this failed.

Login.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="login">
    <login></login>     
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/httpVueLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>  
  <script src="src/login.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Login.js file

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: "#4CAF50",
    secondary: "#2E7D32",
    accent: "#FF4081",
    error: "#f44336",
    warning: "#FFA726",
    info: "#2196f3",
    success: "#4caf50"
  }
})

new Vue({    
  el: '#login',
  components: {
      'login': httpVueLoader('src/Login.vue')
  }
})
```

Login.vue file

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
            <v-card class="elevation-5">
              <v-toolbar color="primary">
                <v-toolbar-title>Member login</v-toolbar-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>                
              </v-toolbar>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="email" label="email" type="text"></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field id="password" prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="primary">Login</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  name: 'login',
  data: function() {
    return {      
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

This displays correct page, but, colors are not adjusted (primary color is green in my theme). Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the minified distribution version of Vuetify's css, passing in custom theme values will have no effect. You need to use the stylus versions and build the css file yourself.

The guide for modifying stylus variables use webpack, so you'll need to follow that or find another way to compile your theme into a css file.

See [Modifying Stylus Variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme)

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I ran into this while not using npm or webpack. I was able to get the theme overrides to work by setting them in a function in the mounted property of my main Vue component, like so:

```
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        watch: {},
        mounted: function() {
            this.$vuetify.theme.primary = '#1b5632';
            this.$vuetify.theme.secondary = '#6AAB84';
        },
        data: {
            domain: 'Sample',
            title: 'Login',
            username: ''
        },
        methods: {},
        router
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Noticed I should edit the place which I use 
Vue.use(Vuetify)

If I add anything after this one it is not affected. But replacing the plain Vue.use(Vuetify) by the one with parameters will fix it.

Same story with RTL

**works**

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  rtl: true
})
```

---

**Does NOT work**

```
Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  rtl: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Themeing Vuetify, this works for me with light & dark mode on:
`\plugins\vuetify.js` add this

```
    export default new Vuetify({
      icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
      },
      theme: {
        themes: {
          light: {
            primary: "#ffcc50",
            error: "#ff8888",
            success: "#45a5ae",

            secondary: '#b0bec5',
            accent: '#8c9eff',
          },
          dark: {
            primary: "#ffcc50",
            error: "#ff8888",
            success: "#45a5ae",

            secondary: '#b0bec5',
            accent: '#8c9eff',

          },
        },
      },

    });
```

Comment: somehow it works but are not we gonna have redundant code? and why is it  working? please add some explanation so I can 1+ ya

Comment: I think it works by dynamically changing the "light" class to "dark". In my example the code seems redundant but it is logical to have different colors for each theme. You can "atomically" modify each color of each theme. Now that I think about it, I could try adding a new theme called (for example) "gray" or "rainbow" with its own color settings. I hope I have helped

Comment: please add your explanation to your post. 